# Protractor E2E Test - Blocked Browser Plugins

Tags: angularjs, protractor, npapi, ppapi

I am creating a suite of tests for a rich angular app in protractor. The site requires macromedia and another proprietary plugin to operate appropriately. I have manually set the "always allowed" flag on the relevant plugins. When these plugins fail to initialize, some detection automatically prompts the user to install/update the plugin. Since the browser blocks them when being run on the selenium server, it blocks the standard anticipated flow of the attempted e2e test.

Right now I am focusing on Chrome for my testing.

Is there a setting I haven't been able to sleuth out either a way to permanently allow these in the spawned chrome instance(s) or to be speedy enough with my cursor to allow the blocked plugins.

Can anyone point me at a method of allowing these plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 30 seconds after posting this question, I found the answer.

In the protractor config file, adding the capabilities  chromeOptions :{args:['--always-authorize-plugins']} did the trick.

```js
exports.config = {
//...
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'Chrome',
        chromeOptions: { args: ['--always-authorize-plugins'] }
    }
//...
};
```